# dart flutter httpclient : authorization

Tags: dart, jwt, flutter

i would like to perform a basic authentication with a simple token; how to perform this in flutter?  which is the best way?

```
var response = await httpClient.post(url, 
    body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
```

is it sufficient to ad an authentication header, for example in this way ?

```
var response = await httpClient.post(
    url, 
    header:{ 
        'authorization' : 'bearer $token', 
        'content-type':'application/json'
    },
    body :{some body});
```

I'm using a JWT token type

Comment: You basically answered yourself.

Comment: David, go ahead and self-answer this question with the header/authorization/content-type code snippet. That should work. Making it a self-answer tells the next reader that "yes, that is a way"

Comment: I've solved the problem using two functions; the first one return a Future, the second which is triggered by the button;it creates the future and manage the response. The http call is made with httpclient as shown before.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to the word Bearer its must be Capitalized other ways it wont work, not sure whats the reason, but for flutter http calls make sure to capitalize that word like this

```
var response = await httpClient.post(
url, 
headers:{ 
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
},
body :{some body});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
var request = new http.Request('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.headers[HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE] = 'application/json';
request.headers[HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION] = token;
request.body = json.encode(loginRequest.toMap());
await client.send(request).then((response) {
  response.stream.bytesToString().then((value) {
    print(value.toString());
    jsonResponse = value.toString();
    completer.complete(jsonResponse);
  });
}).catchError((error) {
    print(error.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) library which has many features.
File uploading is also super easy.
So many things are handled by Dio itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used a dictionary of key/value pairs for the header information.  I use the fromJson method of my dart class to serialize a list of object of type YourClass.

```
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http

  String token = jwtToken;
  var client = http.Client();
  Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
  headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';

  var response = await client
      .post(url,
          headers: headers,
          body: json.encode(param),
          encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
      .timeout(_TIMEOUT);


       if (response.statusCode == 200) {
           var parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
           list = parsed
                .map<YourClass>((json) => YourClass.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
       }
```